# Observable.switchMap does not interrupt Observable

Tags: rx-java2

I don't understand why switchMap doesn't work as expected. 
At first case switchMap doesn't interrupt Observable but at second case it works as expected. Please, explain that behaviour.

```
    val test = TestObserver<Int>()

    Observable.fromArray(10, 20)
        .switchMap({
            // 1. switchMap does not interrupt generator
            Observable.generate(
                Callable{
                    generateSequence(it, { n -> if (n < it + 9) n + 1 else null}).iterator()
                },
                BiConsumer<Iterator<Int>, Emitter<Int>>(){ data, emitter ->
                    if (data.hasNext()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100)
                        emitter.onNext(data.next())
                    }else {
                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
            )
            // 2. switchMap disposes observable
            //Observable.just(it).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        },2)
        .subscribeWith(test)
    test.await()
    // 1. >> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
    // But I expect [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
    // 2. >> [20]
    print(test.values())
```

What I want to do.

In reality my generator do hard work based on value from switchMap and I want interrupt this work if new value is appeared. At the beginning generator start transaction and at the end generator commits or cancels transaction.

Comment: The observable you switch out has to respond to `dispose()`. It should do so by cancelling any operation it is doing. RxJava cannot do that for you, it can only indicate that the subscription is no longer active.

Comment: @BobDalgleish  As I can see generator internally implemented as "GeneratorDisposable" which checks the cancellation at each iteration. If you add doOnDispose then it will not be called at all

Comment: You have to be running on an RxJava interruptible scheduler such as `io()` or `computation()` for the dispose in `switchMap` to work on `generate`.

Comment: @akarnokd I've tried but without success. Can you show me an example? As I saw in the sources the generate work during subscription phase at this point it cannot be canceled.